# getting fatal errors when work with lots of data

Tags: mysql, exception

Below i have attach my code. in my code it stops on the line :

```
cmdUpdate.executenonquery();
```

and after few seconds exception is generated and the catch block is executed.in catch block it says

> fatal error

I dont know why this error occurs.
And one main important thing is firstly i have executed this code without any `LIMIT` condition in the query specified in `cmdPayment` command.then it does not generate any exception. 
But when i remove `LIMIT` condition from query then it generates exception.

This query will select data from table which has around 20.

```
int freeMonths=0;
        string subscriptionTxnId = null;
        string paymentType=null;
        string subscriptionDate = null;
        string userid = null;
        string date = "2014-02-01 00:00:00";

        using (MySqlConnection connPayment = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connPayment.Open();

            freeMonths = 0;

            MySqlCommand cmdPayment = new MySqlCommand("SELECT userid,subscr_txn_id,DATE_FORMAT(subscr_date,'%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s'),payment_type from payment limit 10000",connPayment);
            MySqlDataReader readerPayment;

            readerPayment = cmdPayment.ExecuteReader();




            while (readerPayment.Read())
            {

                try
                {
                    freeMonths = 0;

                    if (readerPayment.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value && readerPayment.GetValue(1) != DBNull.Value && readerPayment.GetValue(2) != DBNull.Value && readerPayment.GetValue(3) != DBNull.Value)
                    {

                        userid = readerPayment.GetString(0);
                        subscriptionTxnId = readerPayment.GetString(1);
                        subscriptionDate = readerPayment.GetString(2);
                        paymentType = readerPayment.GetString(3);


                        using (MySqlConnection connPaymentDetails = new MySqlConnection(connString))
                        {
                            connPaymentDetails.Open();
                            MySqlCommand cmdPaymentDetails = new MySqlCommand("select free_months from payment_details where userid = '" + userid + "' AND subscr_txn_id ='" + subscriptionTxnId + "' AND payment_date = '" + subscriptionDate + "' ", connPaymentDetails);

                            MySqlDataReader readerPaymentDetails = cmdPaymentDetails.ExecuteReader();

                            if (readerPaymentDetails.HasRows)
                            {
                                readerPaymentDetails.Read();

                                freeMonths = readerPaymentDetails.GetInt32(0);
                            }

                        }


                        string query = null;

                        MySqlConnection conUpdate = new MySqlConnection(connString);


                        if (paymentType == "annual" || paymentType == "Annual")
                        {
                            //MySqlCommand cmd001 = new MySqlCommand("")


                            query = "update payment set end_date = (select DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('" + subscriptionDate + "' ,INTERVAL 1 YEAR),INTERVAL '" + freeMonths + "' MONTH)) where subscr_date = '" + subscriptionDate + "' AND userid = '" + userid + "' AND subscr_txn_id ='" + subscriptionTxnId + "' ";
                        }
                        else if (paymentType == "quarter" || paymentType == "Quarter" || paymentType == "Quarterly")
                        {
                            freeMonths += 3;
                            query = "update payment set end_date = (select DATE_ADD('" + subscriptionDate + "', INTERVAL '" + freeMonths + "' MONTH)) where subscr_date = '" + subscriptionDate + "'  AND userid = '" + userid + "' AND subscr_txn_id ='" + subscriptionTxnId + "' ";
                        }
                        else if (paymentType == "month" || paymentType == "Month" || paymentType == "Monthly")
                        {
                            freeMonths += 1;
                            query = "update payment set end_date = (select DATE_ADD('" + subscriptionDate + "', INTERVAL '" + freeMonths + "' MONTH)) where subscr_date = '" + subscriptionDate + "'  AND userid = '" + userid + "' AND subscr_txn_id ='" + subscriptionTxnId + "' ";
                        }

                        MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand(query, conUpdate);
                        conUpdate.Open();
                        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        int num = 0;
                        if (num == 0)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would say you are requesting far too much data in the un LIMITed query.

Comment: 20,000 Data are too much? 20,000 rows with 4 coloumns.? now what can i do?